# my session key doesn't exist even it is stored in DB

Tags: python, django

**when i tried to store the session key in the database, it is successfully done and I can see it from the admin portal, I have used the following code to store the session_key**

```
    if not kwargs.get(('request')).session.session_key:
        kwargs.get(('request')).session.save()
        UserSession.objects.create(
        user=instance,
        IPAddress=get_IP(kwargs.get('request')),
        sessionkey=kwargs.get(('request')).session.session_key)
```

**The following is my model**

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    IPAddress = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    sessionkey=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ended=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**but when i tried to access it using **

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session.objects.get(pk='0wjxg94sr5aosndyit7ki1dhuiuw6ovg')
```

**it gave me the following error **

```
django.contrib.sessions.models.DoesNotExist: Session matching query does not exist
```

**and indeed didn't find my session_key when i used the following command **

```
Session.objects.all()
```

Comment: Why do you want to access the session key? Sessions are stored automatically.

Comment: I need to delete the old session for the same user using Session.objects.get(pk='0wjxg94sr5aosndyit7ki1dhuiuw6ovg').delete()

Comment: Old sessions are flushed/deleted when a user logs out

Comment: @OluwafemiSuleI know but when the user, for example, open session, then open incognito window for example so the user will have 2 sessions active and I think it isn't good so I need to delete the old one